# Tree data in live streaming. Is this feasible with viewport row model?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am exploring ag grid features. As I understand for documentation, viewport row model supports live streaming of data.

I wanted to know if we can have tree data view with live streaming/ viewport row mode?

As per the documentation, I see tree data view is mentioned in client side row model and server side row model

And we cant have client side sorting and filtering with viewport model?

Comment: Can  do streaning implementation with client row model with applytransaction https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update-high-frequency/

Comment: what is the difference in flushtransaction and viewport